# Powershell - Split a string

Tags: regex, string, powershell

I'm trying to split a string in power-shell... I've already done some work on the string, but i can't figure out this last part.

Say I'm sitting with this string:

```
This is a string. Its a comment that's anywhere from 5 to 250 characters wide.
```

I want to split it at the 30 character mark, but I don't want to split a word. If I was to split it, it would have "... commen" on one line... "t that..." on the next line.

What's a graceful way of splitting the string, 50max, without breaking a word in half? Say for simplicity sake a word is a space (comments might have numeric text "$1.00" in it as well. Don't want to split that in half either).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$regex = [regex] "\b"
$str = "This is a string. Its a comment that's anywhere from 5 to 250 characters wide."
$split = $regex.split($str, 2, 30)
```

Comment: So what is this doing here exactly?

Comment: @DanielLoveJr - The code uses [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0zfk0w1.aspx) of `Regex.Split` so it splits the input string into a maximum of two pieces on the first word boundary (the `\b` regex) starting from the 31st character.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how graceful it is, but one way to do it would be to use lastindexof on a substring 30 characters long to find your largest, sub 30 character value.

```
$str = "This is a string. Its a comment that's anywhere from 5 to 250 characters wide."
$thirtychars = $str.substring(0,30)
$sen1 = $str.substring(0,$thirtychars.lastindexof(" ")+1)
$sen2 = $str.substring($thirtychars.lastindexof(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "words" are tokens that are space delimited.

```
$str = "This is a string. Its a comment that's anywhere from 5 to 250 characters wide."
$q = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.Queue[String] (,[string[]]$str.Split(" "));
$newstr = ""; while($newstr.length -lt 30){$newstr += $q.deQueue()+" "}
```

Tokenize the string (split on spaces), which creates an array.  Creating the Queue object with the array in the constructor, automatically populates the queue; then, you just "pop" the items off the queue until the length of the new string is as close as it can get to the limit.

Note the quaint syntax `,[string[]]$str.Split(" ")` to make the constructor work properly.

mp